# Conditional with multiple conditions, one of which is a string search

Tags: conditionals, strings, xstring

**Aim**

I want a command to write "where `#1` is an arbitrary constant", "where `#1` are arbitrary constants", "where `#1` is an arbitrary function of `#2`", or "where `#1` are arbitrary functions of `#2`", as appropriate.

**Background**

Usually it's enough to let singular-plural detection rely on the presence or absence of a comma in `#1`. For that, the following function works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,xargs,xifthen,amsmath}
\newcommandx{\arbitrary}[3][1=\text{ where }, 3=]{%
    #1#2%
    \IfSubStr{#2}{,}{\text{ are}}{\text{ is an}}%
    \text{ arbitrary}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{\text{ constant}}{\text{ function}}%
    \IfSubStr{#2}{,}{\text{s}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\text{ of }#3}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        & \arbitrary{a} \\ % where a is an arbitrary constant
        & \arbitrary{a,b} \\ % where a,b are arbitrary constants
        & \arbitrary{f}[x] \\ % where f is an arbitrary function of x
        & \arbitrary{f,g}[x] % where f,g are arbitrary functions of x
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But sometimes I want to pluralise a singular-looking argument, like

```
2a_n+1, \text{ where $a_n$ are arbitrary constants, } n \in \{1,2,\dots\}
```

For this I'm trying to implement a backup detection mechanism, using an optional argument. This involves defining two conditions on which the function will treat `#1` as plural: if `#1` contains a comma, or if `#4=p` for plural.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,xargs,xifthen}
\newcommandx{\arbitrary}[4][1=\text{ where }, 3=, 4=]{%
    #1#2%
    \ifthenelse{%
        1=\IfSubStr{#2}{,}{1}{0}\OR%
        \equal{#4}{p}%
    }{\text{ are}}{\text{ is}}%
    \text{ arbitrary}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{\text{ constant}}{\text{ function}}%
    \ifthenelse{%
        1=\IfSubStr{#2}{,}{1}{0}\OR%
        \equal{#4}{p}%
    }{\text{s}}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\text{ of }#3}
}
\begin{document}
    I wish this function worked.
\end{document}
```

**Problem**

LaTeX seems not to like the syntax `\ifthenelse{1=\IfSubStr{ab}{a}{1}{0}}{1}{0}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,xifthen}
\begin{document}
    \IfSubStr{ab}{a}{1}{0} % returns 1
    \ifthenelse{1=1}{1}{0} % returns 1
    \ifthenelse{1=\IfSubStr{ab}{a}{1}{0}}{1}{0} % returns error
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extended version that also copes with multivariate functions. The *-version forces plural.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\arbitrary}{smo}
 {% #1 = boolean for forcing plural
  % #2 = mandatory argument
  % #3 = optional argument for the variable
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \bool_set_true:N \l_mjc_arbitrary_plural_bool }
   { \bool_set_false:N \l_mjc_arbitrary_plural_bool }
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   { \mjc_arbitrary_constant:n { #2 } }
   { \mjc_arbitrary_function:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\bool_new:N \l_mjc_arbitrary_plural_bool
\seq_new:N \l__mjc_arbitrary_variables_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mjc_arbitrary_variables_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mjc_arbitrary_constant:n
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
   { \l_mjc_arbitrary_plural_bool }
   { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #1 } > 1 } }
   { \mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn { #1 } { are } { constants } { } }
   { \mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn { #1 } { is~an } { constant } { } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mjc_arbitrary_function:nn
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
   { \l_mjc_arbitrary_plural_bool }
   { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #1 } > 1 } }
   { \mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn { #1 } { are } { functions } { #2 } }
   { \mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn { #1 } { is~an } { functions } { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn
 {% #1 = object, #2 = verb, #3 = type, #4 = optional variable
  \mode_if_math:TF 
   { \text { \__mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } } }
   { \__mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mjc_arbitrary_phrases:nnnn
 {
  where~$#1$~#2~arbitrary~#3
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #4 }
   {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__mjc_arbitrary_variables_seq { #4 }
    \c_space_tl of~the~variable
    \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__mjc_arbitrary_variables_seq > 1 } { s }
    \nobreakspace
    \__mjc_arbitrary_variables:
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mjc_arbitrary_variables:
 {
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__mjc_arbitrary_variables_out_seq \l__mjc_arbitrary_variables_seq { $##1$ }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__mjc_arbitrary_variables_out_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and\nobreakspace }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \arbitrary{a} \\ % where a is an arbitrary constant
& \arbitrary*{a_n} \\ % where a_n are arbitrary constants
& \arbitrary{a,b} \\ % where a,b are arbitrary constants
& \arbitrary{f}[x] \\ % where f is an arbitrary function of x
& \arbitrary{f,g}[x] \\% where f,g are arbitrary functions of x
& \arbitrary{f}[x,y] \\ % where f is an arbitrary function of x and y
& \arbitrary{f,g}[x,y] \\% where f,g are arbitrary functions of x, y, and z
& \arbitrary*{f_n}[x] \\ % where f is an arbitrary function of x
& \arbitrary*{f_n}[x,y] % where f is an arbitrary function of x and y
\end{align*}

\arbitrary{a},
\arbitrary*{a_n},
\arbitrary{a,b},
\arbitrary{f}[x],
\arbitrary{f,g}[x],
\arbitrary*{f_n}[x].

\end{document}
```

I only use `\text` if the command is found in math mode; in text mode you don't want to make the thing unbreakable across lines.

Slight complication is using `~` where you want a space, but it just requires a bit of practice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to condition on the presence of `,` within your first argument (via `\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}`). That provides the first conditional branch. Then I condition on the existence of a closing optional argument using [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s `\IfValueTF{<arg>}{<true>}{<false>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{xparse}% Only if you have LaTeX < 2020-10
\usepackage{etoolbox,amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arbitrary}{m o}{
  \def\firstarg{#1}% Store mandatory argument
  \text{ where }
  \firstarg
  \IfValueTF{#2}
    {\patchcmd{\firstarg}{,}{,}
      {\text{ are arbitrary functions of } #2}% Contains a comma , => plural
      {\text{ is an arbitrary function of } #2}}% Does not contain a comma , => singular
    {\patchcmd{\firstarg}{,}{,}
      {\text{ are arbitrary constants}}% Contains a comma , => plural
      {\text{ is an arbitrary constant}}}% Does not contain a comma , => singular
}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & \arbitrary{a} \\ % where a is an arbitrary constant
  & \arbitrary{a,b} \\ % where a,b are arbitrary constants
  & \arbitrary{f}[x] \\ % where f is an arbitrary function of x
  & \arbitrary{f,g}[x] % where f,g are arbitrary functions of x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

If you want to *force* a plural output for a singular item, you could adapt `\arbitrary` to take a star - `\arbitrary*`. This is how you'd condition using that:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{xparse}% Only if you have LaTeX < 2020-10
\usepackage{etoolbox,amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\arbitrary}{s m o}{
  \def\firstarg{#2}% Store mandatory argument
  \text{ where }
  \firstarg
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\text{ are arbitrary constants}}% Starred version => plural
    {
    \IfValueTF{#3}
      {\patchcmd{\firstarg}{,}{,}
        {\text{ are arbitrary functions of } #3}% Contains a comma , => plural
        {\text{ is an arbitrary function of } #3}}% Does not contain a comma , => singular
      {\patchcmd{\firstarg}{,}{,}
        {\text{ are arbitrary constants}}% Contains a comma , => plural
        {\text{ is an arbitrary constant}}}% Does not contain a comma , => singular
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & \arbitrary{a} \\ % where a is an arbitrary constant
  & \arbitrary*{a_n} \\ % where a_n are arbitrary constants
  & \arbitrary{a,b} \\ % where a,b are arbitrary constants
  & \arbitrary{f}[x] \\ % where f is an arbitrary function of x
  & \arbitrary{f,g}[x] % where f,g are arbitrary functions of x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to replicate the functionality of the original command, but does it handle the exception I described? If my original syntax had worked, I would have written `\arbitrary{a_n}[][p]` and got "where $a_n$ are arbitrary constants". Could you clarify how I can do that with your command?

Comment: @mjc: Sure it does. You should try it! The only thing that distinguishes between singular or plural usage is a `,` (comma) in the first/mandatory argument. Since `a_n` doesn't have a `,`, it's considered singular. Note though that it won't work if you pass a macro that has your list of items in there (for example, `\newcommand{\itemlist}{a_n, b_n}` and then use `\arbitrary{\itemlist}` will print a singular phrase).

Comment: "Since `a_n` doesn't have a `,` it's considered singular.". Right; that's the problem that motivated the OP. I want the option to treat singular-looking expressions like `a_n` as plural.

Comment: @mjc - You wrote, "I want the option to treat singular-looking expressions like `a_n` as plural." Do your readers somehow know that `a_n` is a plural object even though it sure looks like a singular object?

Comment: @Mico Letting them know that is the purpose of describing it that way. The plural construction comes from the lecturer of the course module I'm working on. I suppose "$(a_n)$ is a sequence of arbitrary constants" would be more accurate, but I'm going with the flow.

Comment: @mjc If  "$(a_n)$ is a sequence of arbitrary constants", then it is singular, because it is a "sequence".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes. That's not the phrase I'm trying to use.

Comment: @mjc: How about [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/jsh3LvGt) as an option? For the odd case you want to force as plural, use `\arbitrary*{a_n}`.

Comment: @Werner Yes, that works, thanks.